# How do Ruby min and max compare strings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm playing around with iterators. What is Ruby comparing using `max` and `min`?

If I have this array:

```
word_array = ["hi", "bob", "how's", "it", "going"]
```

and I run:

```
puts word_array.max
puts word_array.min
```

I expect to get "going" or "how's" for `max`, since they're both five characters long, or "going" on the theory that it's the last item in the array. I expect `min` to return "hi" or "it", since they're tied for the shortest string. Instead, I get back:

```
puts word_array.max -> it
puts word_array.min -> bob
```

What is Ruby measuring to make this judgement? It selected the shortest string for `max` and a middle length string for `min`.

Comment: it appears to be taking max to be the highest letter in the alphabet. Namely `b > a` etc. Similarly for min. Try the array `['a','b','c','d']` to see more easily how 'max' and 'min' work.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, you are (kind of) asking the wrong question. [`max`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-max) and [`min`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-min) are defined on [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html). They don't know anything about [`String`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html)s.

They use the `<=>` combined comparison operator (aka "spaceship"). (Note: pretty much *any* method that compares two objects will do so using the `<=>` operator. That's a general rule in Ruby that you can both rely on when using objects other people have written and that you should adhere to when writing your own objects: if your objects are going to be compared to one another, you should implement the `<=>` operator.)

So, the question you *should* be asking is, how does [`String#<=>`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) compare `String`s? Unfortunately, the answer is not quite clear from the documentation. However, it *does* mention that the shorter string is considered to be less than the longer string if the two strings are equal up to that point. So, it is clear that length is used *only* as a tie-breaker, *not* as the primary criterion (as you are assuming in your question).

And really, lexicographic ordering is just the most natural thing to do. If I gave you a list of words and asked you to order them without giving you any criteria, would you order them by length or alphabetically? (Note, however, that this means that `'20'` is *less than* `'3'`.)

Answer (score 3):

I believe it's doing a lexical sort, exactly like a dictionary order. The maximum would be the furthest one in the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by

```
ar = ['one','two','three','four','five']
ar.max_by(&:length) # => "three"
```